# TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: next.js, strapi

I am trying to migrate my v3 strapi app to v4 on my local machine with the local database. I am trying to perform code migration. Initially I have changed the config files following the documentation of strapi v4. I have used codemods to change the folder structure and to update the routes, controllers and services.

Now when I am trying to run my strapi application I am getting this error and the app build is breaking.

[image]

These are my route, controller, services and schema.json file

route:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * blog router
 */

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::blog.blog');


Controller:

'use strict';

/**
 * blog controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::blog.blog');


service:

'use strict';

/**
 * blog service
 */

const { createCoreService } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreService('api::blog.blog');


schema.json:

{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "blogs",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "blog",
    "pluralName": "blogs",
    "displayName": "Blog",
    "name": "blog"
  },
  "options": {
    "increments": true,
    "timestamps": true,
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "insightImage": {
      "type": "media",
      "allowedTypes": [
        "images",
        "files",
        "videos"
      ],
      "multiple": false,
      "required": false
    },
    "insightTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "insightDescription": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "insightContent": {
      "type": "richtext"
    },
    "slug": {
      "type": "string",
      "unique": true
    },
    "categories": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToMany",
      "target": "api::category.category",
      "mappedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "insightDate": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "views": {
      "type": "integer",
      "default": 0
    },
    "featured": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "frontImage": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "insightsMetaData": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": false,
      "component": "meta.metadata"
    },
    "industry": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::industry.industry",
      "inversedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "solution": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::solution.solution",
      "inversedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::type.type",
      "inversedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "featured_topics": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToMany",
      "target": "api::featured-topic.featured-topic",
      "inversedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "formTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "formId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "author": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "manyToOne",
      "target": "api::author.author",
      "inversedBy": "blogs"
    },
    "enableGated": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "insightBannerImage": {
      "type": "media",
      "allowedTypes": [
        "images",
        "files",
        "videos"
      ],
      "multiple": false,
      "required": false
    },
    "breakTitleText": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look through all the collections you have created and delete the once without `content-types` folder or `schema.js`. You can recreate them later.

That was my issue.